# latin characters getting displayed as junk characters from the webdriver getText() command

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have a requirement where I am trying to automate the registration form which is in French language, while automating I am trying to get the text of the error messages which are in French(localised) language.

Example code snippet:

```
String text=driver.getText(By.cssSelector("#first_name + label.error"));//which gets the localised error message string
```

When I print the text some junk characters are getting printed.
Actual output which is printed:

```
Seulement alphabets, des chiffres et des espaces sont autorisï¿½
```

Expected output: `Seulement Alphabets, des chiffres et des espaces sont autorisés`

I am trying to `assertEquals(actualoutput,expectedoutput)` which is getting failed

I am getting the expected output from the `language.properties` file where translated text is there(which is  UTF-8 converted and loaded as properties file).

I have even tried to convert the actual output to UTF-8 with the below code

```
byte ptext[] = text.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
actualMessage=new String(ptext,"UTF-8");
```

But still it is not working getting printed with the junk characters as mentioned above. (`Seulement alphabets, des chiffres et des espaces sont autorisï¿½)`
Does the getText() gets the text in  UTF-8 converted?

Please let me know your thoughts on this and help me.

Thanks
Sairkishna

Comment: Have you looked at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22516207/automating-nonenglish-website-using-webdriver

Comment: yes, the question i have posted is with something else,it does not give solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

`.properties` files in Java use always ISO-8859-1. You are not able to save UTF-8 characters into `.properties` files. You must save the characters as unicode escape characters.

In your example the value of the key must look like this:

```
Seulement Alphabets, des chiffres et des espaces sont autoris\u00E9s
```

Take a look here: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e9/index.htm

With this solution you do not need any convert of the character set in your Java code. Just read the content of your `.properties` file.

There exist also some nice Eclipse plugins to edit `.properties` files who automatically convert text into the right format.